# Does a search spider crawl elements that have been removed with js?

Tags: javascript, seo, web-crawler

I am removing some elements from the dom with jQuery's `remove()`  Looking in firebug I can see that the elements are removed but viewing the source of the page they are there.  My question is how do bots interpret this.  When they crawl would they essentially be seeing what I see when I view source or would the view of the removed elements that Firebug shows be more accurate?

Comment: Simple answer - bot's always read the page source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoogleBot, for example, does execute JavaScript, but not always concurrently with crawling your site (it stores the JS in a queue and executes it as resources become available). Don't count on JavaScript for removing page elements that shouldn't be accessible. Bots and humans alike can always view your source, and JavaScript does nothing to alter the source code.